# git: Conflicts remaining after squash and merge via github

Tags: git, github, merge

On this project we have `master`, `staging`, and `develop` branches. All feature branches branch from `develop` and are squashed and merged back into `develop` via GitHub's squash and merge pull request feature. Once we're ready for a release we merge into `staging` and eventually `master` (production).

Throughout the project there have been various hot fixes to `master` (production) and that can cause some conflicts when we do a release by merging `develop` into `staging` and then `staging` into `master`.

In order to mitigate against this I tried the following.

1. Create new branch from `develop` i.e. branch name `fix-conflicts`
2. Pull in `master` to `fix-conflicts` and resolve conflicts
3. Pull in `staging` to `fix-conflicts` and resolve conflicts
4. Create pull request on `fix-conflicts` to merge into `develop`
5. Squash and merge pull request

After this I create a new branch from `develop` (after getting latest) I expect if I pull in `master` there should be no more conflicts as I have already resolved them. But this isn't the case - the same conflicts remain. I suspect it's linked to the squash and merge causing it to forget about the meta data associated with the updates, but would like to hear your thoughts on this.

This issue has really made me realise how little I know about git

Comment: Why don't you simply rebase your develop and staging branch against master?

Comment: @Jan thanks - so could I rebase a feature branch against master and then merge that into develop? Would that work?

Comment: I don't know the whole situation but if both branches have it's source in your `master` this should work. Please pay attention on rebasing you have to push with force afterwards. This can lead to serious problems if you don't pay attention. A backup may be a good idea!